# Erase lines on a dataframe based on a specific calculation

Tags: r

I have a dataframe like this :

[mydata](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rioUm.jpg)

and I would like to erase a specific amount of lines based on the IDNumber and #Paymts.

Basically I want to **keep only the 2 last lines** for each IDNumber. For example, for IDNumber = 230, i have 5 lines (indicated in the column #Paymts), I want to erase all the first lines and just keep the two last.

Any idea ? 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `slice`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   group_by(IDNumber) %>%
   slice(tail(row_number(), 2)) #or
   #slice((n()-1):n())
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
df1 <- data.frame(IDNumber = rep(LETTERS[1:3], each = 5), Date = Sys.Date(), 
   `#Paymts` = sample(1:9, 15, replace = TRUE), check.names = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

```
trimmed_df = df[unlist(tapply(rownames(df), df$id_number, tail,  2)), ]
```